# Error in time XUnit testing of the controller in .net Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, xunit

I try to test the controller in .net Core, but in time the test arises an error which I could not correct. The problem arises with mock context, by its transfer to the controller.

Example of a context:

```
public class Context : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<Exercise> ExerciseSet { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Tag> TagSet { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Type> TypeSet { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Difficulty> DifficultySet { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<ExerciseTag> ExerciseTagSet { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Mark> MarkSet { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<ExerciseMark> ExerciseMarkSet { get; set; }

    public Context(DbContextOptions<Context> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

Example of the test:

```
public class TagControllerTest
{
    [Fact]
    public void SimpleTest()
    {
        Assert.Equal(5, 5);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void SimpleTest2()
    {
        Assert.Equal(5, 5);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void ControllerGetTest()
    {
        //Arrange
        var data = new List<Tag>
        {
            public virtual DbSet<Exercise> ExerciseSet { get; set; }
            public virtual DbSet<Tag> TagSet { get; set; }
            public virtual DbSet<Type> TypeSet { get; set; }
            public virtual DbSet<Difficulty> DifficultySet { get; set; }
            public virtual DbSet<ExerciseTag> ExerciseTagSet { get; set; }
            public virtual DbSet<Mark> MarkSet { get; set; }
            public virtual DbSet<ExerciseMark> ExerciseMarkSet { get; set; }
       }.AsQueryable();

        Mock<DbSet<Tag>> dbSetMock = new Mock<DbSet<Tag>>();
        dbSetMock.As<IQueryable<Tag>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(data.Provider);
        dbSetMock.As<IQueryable<Tag>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(data.Expression);
        dbSetMock.As<IQueryable<Tag>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(data.ElementType);
        dbSetMock.As<IQueryable<Tag>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(data.GetEnumerator());

        Mock<Context> context = new Mock<Context>(dbSetMock.Object);
        context.Setup(x => x.TagSet).Returns(dbSetMock.Object);

        TagController controller = new TagController(context.Object);

        // Act
        var result = controller.GetTag();

        // Assert
        Assert.NotNull(result);
    }
}
```

The first two tests pass, but the third test gives an error message in line:

```
TagController controller = new TagController(context.Object);
```

> Message: Castle.DynamicProxy.InvalidProxyConstructorArgumentsException
>   : Can not instantiate proxy of class: interview.Models.Context. Could
>   not find a constructor that would match given arguments:
>   Castle.Proxies.DbSet`1Proxy

Answer (score 0):

```
Mock<Context> context = new Mock<Context>(dbSetMock.Object);
```

The context's constructor accepts `DbContextOptions<Context>` but you pass `DbSet<Tag>`.

In general, add a parameterless constructor or pass something like:

```
var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<Context>();
var options = builder.Options;
```